# E[M(cells)/2] where F(t) is the probability that cells die in t

Tags: probability, central-limit-theorem

Lets m be a population of cells in $t=0$ (very big population) and $M(t)$ the number of alive cells a time t, so $M(0)=m$. Each cell has a probability $F(t)$ to have die in $(0,t)$ (independent to the other cells). F(t) is de CDF of the time to die of a cell.

What is the time $t_0$ when the expected number of cells alive is $M(t_0)=m/2$? and, Why?

I suppose that $t_0$ should be the time that $(1-F(t_0))=\frac{1}{2}$ but I can't find why, I review the limits theorems but I can't find the relation whit this problem.

Comment: The phrase "has a probability to die in $F(t)$" makes no sense: perhaps some words are missing?

Comment: I edited the question to clarify it

Comment: Thank you.  Just to make sure: are you saying that there is a single function $F$ such that for *any* cell in the population, its chance of being dead at time $t$ is $F(t)$?  If that's so, then here's a hint: solve the problem first for the case $M=1$.

Comment: Why is $t_0$ even guaranteed to exist?  You'd need some conditions on $F$ or restate the question.  Perhaps you'd want to model this as a continuous rather than what appears to be a discrete process?

Answer (score 0):

Lets say $I_i$ is the indicator función of a cell that $I_i(t)=1$ if the cell ith is alive at t and is $I_i=0$ otherwise. $E[I_i(t_0)]=I_i*F(t_0)=1/2$ so  $E[M(t_0)]=E[I_1(t_0)+I_2(t_0)+...+I_m(t_0)]=E[I_1(t_0)]+...+E[I_M(t_0)]=m/2$

Is it correct?

Comment: How does $M$ go from being a random variable to being a constant?

Comment: I do not see any need to invoke the independence assumption, but as @dsaxton remarks in a comment to your question, you will need to make some assumptions about $F$.

Comment: @will198: Assuming $F(t)$ is continuous, $E[I_i(t_0)] = 1-F(t_0)$. So $E[M] = [1-F(t_0)]M$, from which you conclude $F(t_0)=1/2$ is the right value for $t_0$.

Comment: @AlexR. If $F(t)$ is continuous then it can't be a probability of death at time $t$ and the whole process is ill-defined.

Comment: @dsaxton: OPs phrasing is ill defined along with their notation. I guessed maybe $F(t)$ is the CDF given the words "to time time t".

Comment: I edited the question and my answer with your comments. I hope now all is clear and correct.